# How I LOGIN in other website through my form

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

I tring to post in https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login with login and password directly from my website form like it:

```
<form method="post" action="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank">
  <div>
    <label>Choose a file</label>
    <input type="text" id="file" name="login">
  </div>
   <div>
    <label >Choose a file</label>
    <input type="text" name="passwd">   
    </div>
  <div>
    <button>GO To Sharepont</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

But when I clik in the button return erro from microsoft is missing a TOKEN.
How can I login in other site through my site form?

Comment: You can get more information about the error here: [Login error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/94885/aadsts900561-the-endpoint-only-accepts-post-reques.html)

Comment: Hi @FernandoValderramaGuayán, I read the link but It did not healp me. It's not about 3rd party extension. Its about input username and password for my form to another website like sharepoint.